# Getting TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/XXXX error for TF Command

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc

I have tried the below command as inline script in powershell task with "*Azure Pipelines*" as Agent Pool and "*vs2017-win2016*" as Agent Specification.

*TF merge $/ProjectX/SourceBranch $/ProjectX/TargetBranch /recursive /noprompt /login:XXXXX@domain.com,XXPWDXX*

But getting the error as "*TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/XXXXXXX*"

I have also tried the login option as /login:domain\username,password and /login:PAT. But getting the same error.

Please anyone let me know how to fix this issue.

*Note: I have administrator permission to my project.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **OAuth token** instead. Try to check the option `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` in the agent job, and then use `System.AccessToken` variable in your script, something like `/loginType:OAuth /login:.,$(System.AccessToken)`

[image]